# How can I select three distinct points are not collinear?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list

```
list = {{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 
   5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {7, 
   5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 
   1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 
   2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 
   7}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 
   8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 
   1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 
   7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 
   1}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 
   2, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 
   4}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 
   5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 
   2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 
   6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 
   5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 
   6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 
   5}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 
   7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}}
```

I tried

```
Select[list, MatrixRank[#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]] == 2 &]
```

I get the empty set.

Comment: Your "Select" function has wring syntax. Try: `Select[list, MatrixRank[#] == 3 &]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
result=Pick[list, Not@*CollinearPoints /@ list]
```

> `{{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6,  3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8,  7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2,  1}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3,  2, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8,  7}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2,  5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6,  3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {8,  7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7,  5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5,  6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2,  1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3,  2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5,  1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8,  7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5,  1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}}`

```
Area /@ Triangle /@ result
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 
     7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 
     4}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 
     7}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
     3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 
     1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 
     7}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 
     2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 
     3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 
     4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
     3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 
     1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 
     4}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 
     2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 
     3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
     1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
     1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
     3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
     1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 
     1}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
     1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}};

r1 = Select[Area@Triangle@# > 0 &][list];
r2 = Select[Abs@Det@# > 0 &][list];
r3 = Select[MatrixRank@# == 3 &][list];
r4 = Select[VectorAngle @@ Subtract @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] != 0 &][
   list];
r1 == r2 == r3 == r4
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Just one more way to do it is the following:

```
list = {{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 
 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 
 4}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 
 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 
 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 
 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 
 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 
 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 
 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
 3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 
 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 
 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 
 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 
 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
 1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 
 1}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}};

Cases[#, m_ /; NullSpace[m] == {}] &@list

    {{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 
   3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8, 
   7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 
   1}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 
   2, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 
   7}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 
   5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
   3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {8, 
   7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 
   5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 
   6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
   1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 
   2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 
   1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 
   7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
   1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is the following:

```
list[[Flatten[
   Position[DiagonalMatrixQ@RowReduce[#] & /@ list, True]]]]
```

Output is:

> `{{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6,  3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8,  7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2,  1}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3,  2, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8,  7}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2,  5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6,  3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {8,  7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7,  5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5,  6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2,  1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3,  2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5,  1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8,  7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5,  1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}}`

The original list

```
list = {{{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {3, 
     7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 
     4}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {2, 5, 4}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 
     7}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
     3}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 2, 
     1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{1, 8, 
     7}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 
     2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {5, 6, 
     3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{1, 8, 7}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 
     4}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
     3}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 1}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 2, 
     1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{2, 5, 
     4}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 
     2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {5, 6, 
     3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{2, 5, 4}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
     1}, {3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
     1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {3, 7, 5}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 
     3}, {7, 5, 1}}, {{3, 2, 1}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 2, 
     1}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 
     1}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {5, 6, 3}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{3, 7, 5}, {7, 5, 
     1}, {8, 7, 2}}, {{5, 6, 3}, {7, 5, 1}, {8, 7, 2}}};
```